# Failed: Login to roundcube

Tags: dovecot, login, roundcube

Where I did I make a mistake? I can not log into roundcube.

```
IMAP Error in /var/www/sub/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php
(193): Login failed for email@mydomain.com from IP.IP.IP.IP. Could not
connect to localhost:143: The time limit for the connection timed out.
```

From logs:

```
dovecot: imap-login: Error: SSL: Stacked error: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown: SSL alert number 46
dovecot: imap-login: Error: SSL: Stacked error: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca: SSL alert number 48
dovecot: imap-login: Error: SSL: Stacked error: error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init
dovecot: imap-login: Error: SSL: Stacked error: error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher
```

Comment: use secure port to connect for IMAP i.e. 993 instead of 143 to connect.

Comment: @Forse I'm not familiar with Roundcube (looks nice) but I guess I would start with making sure dovecot works first before continuing any further since it can operate independently of a web interface.

Comment: @Forse If you don't get it working, post Roundcube and Dovecot configurations please (relating to IMAP).